# Is it possible to create cross dependency on a file?

Tags: workload-scheduler

I want to run a job based on file availability in Tivoli Workload Scheduler. Is it possible to add cross dependency on a file , when the job is local.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with "cross" dependencies in this context.

To wait for a file in Tivoli Workload Scheduler you have the following alternative:

- File dependencies (a.k.a. [opens](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/distr/src_ref/awsrgchddadch.htm)). The job will wait until the
  specified `test` check is satisfied. This is the preferred solution is your workload is scheduled and you just want to wait for a file that you know would come.
- Use a job or a [start condition](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/distr/src_ref/awsrgtrigger.htm) that runs [filemonitor](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/distr/src_ref/awsrgfilemonitor.htm) utility. This is the best solution if you have multiple files that arrives during the day, that you want to process one-by-one or in batches, and that you want to monitor their arrivals.
- EDWA file events. Create an event rule that [monitors for a file creation, update, deletion](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.5.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.5/distr/src_ref/awsrgfilemonitorevents.htm) and that submits your job streams (or job). This is the most dynamic solution to trigger workload dynamically based on files to process one by one and that could come or not.

Comment: A cross dependency is a dependency of a local job on a remote job running in a different scheduling environment.

Comment: I have to add dependency on a file which is existing in a remote engine. So is it possible to apply  cross dependency here?

Comment: Ah, OK. You was actually referring to cross dependency.
You can apply cross dependencies only to jobs, that job can have a file dependency, wait a filemonitor, or can be added by an event rule.

Consider to have an 2 agents on the same environment where the file is created, in this way you won't need cross dependencies

Comment: is there any option to add dependency on a file which is existing on different application server

Comment: 1) add and agent on the server where the file is created, or 2) add a job with a file dep on the env that already has an agent, and add a cross dependency between the two environments